# MognoDB - Aggregate count of arrays based on date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

So I'm trying to make an aggregation query. I have documents that look like this:

```py
{
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "value": [1,2],
    "date": ISODate("2016-06-02T03:02:00.000Z")
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "value": [1,2],
    "date": ISODate("2016-06-06T03:02:00.000Z")
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "value": [3,2],
    "date": ISODate("2017-04-06T03:02:00.000Z")
}
```

I want to count the number of times the same array, `value` has occurred in a specific year-month.

I have gotten the date by writing this aggregation:

```py
{
    "$group":
    {
        '_id':
        {
            "$dateToString":
            {
                "format": "%Y-%m",
                "date": "$launch_time"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort":
    {
        "_id": -1
    }
},
{
    "$project":
    {
        "date": "$_id",
        "_id": 0,
    }
}
```

Which gives me the result:

```py
{'date': '2016-04'} ..so on
```

And I've managed to count the arrays with:

```py
{
    "$group":
    {
        "_id": "$home_coordinates",
        "count":
        {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives me the output:

```py
{'_id': [1,2], 'count': 2} ..so on
```

How do I combine these 2 in such a way that my result looks like this?

```py
{
    "date": "2016-06",
    "value": [1,2],
    "count": 2
},
{
    "date": "2017-04",
    "value": [3,2],
    "count": 1
}
```

> Hence, how do I count the similar arrays based on **date**?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$addFields:{
    date:{ $substr: ["$date", 0, 10] }

    }
},
{
$group:{
    _id:"$date",
    date:{$first:"$date"},
    value:{$first:"$value"},
    count:{$sum:1}
    }
}
])
```